# Is it possible to use foreach in groupingBy in java stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list with books. There is:

 List(string) of authors

 title(string) of book

 and rating (double)

I would like to calculate average for each author of him books. 

 Problem is the list of authors, if I get one author for one book, It will be no problem. I would to solve it like this:

```
Map<String, Double> result = books.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors
                            .groupingBy(Book::getAuthor, TreeMap::new, Collectors
                            .averagingDouble(Book::getRating)
```

Anyone have solution?

Comment: Try to use flatmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would map to a `SimpleEntry` containing each author along with their book to make it easier to group.

With this one can maintain both the author along with the book object thus enabling one to extract any information from the book object upon passing the downstream collector.

example:

```
Map<String, Double> resultSet = 
           books.stream()
                .flatMap(book -> book.getAuthors()
                                     .stream()
                       .map(author -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(author, book)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(e -> e.getValue().getRating())));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Long> result = books.stream()
.flatMap(i -> i.getAuthors().stream())
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
Collectors.counting()));
```

**flatten** authors and `groupingBy` `identity` with `counting` can achieve this.